# Azure web app github continious deployment doesn't completed

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery, azure-webapps

I've a github repo and it's related to an Azure webApp, but the programmatically deployment doesn't completed doesn't complete, the content of repository cloned to the web app directory is partially missing, maybe the timeout is the cause ?

Comment: What is the language, framework, etc.

Comment: We use a wordpress project containing the Versionpress plugin.